# How to partition dataframe rows into bins with calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,3,7,8,8,9], 'y':[1,0,1,1,1,0,1]})
df
   x  y
0  1  1
1  1  0
2  3  1
3  7  1
4  8  1
5  8  0
6  9  1
```

which I'd like to partition into bins [(1,3), (3,5), (5,7), (7,9), (9,11)] (leftbound inclusive, rightbound exclusive).  For each group, I'd like to get the number of rows that went into the bin, and the portion of 1s in each group.

Result should be another dataframe like

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'LB':[1,3,5,7,9], 'RB':[2,4,6,8,10], 'N':[2,1,0,3,1], 'Pcnt1':[.5,1,np.nan,2/3,1]})
print(result)
   LB  N     Pcnt1  RB
0   1  2  0.500000   2
1   3  1  1.000000   4
2   5  0       NaN   6
3   7  3  0.666667   8
4   9  1  1.000000  10
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
bin_edges = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
bins = pd.cut(df.x, bin_edges, right=False)

df_new = pd.DataFrame({"LB": bin_edges[:-1], "RB": bin_edges[1:]})
binned = df.groupby(bins.values.codes)["y"]
df_new["N"] = binned.count()
df_new["N"] = df_new["N"].fillna(0)
df_new["Pcnt1"] = binned.mean()
```

which gives

```
>>> df_new
   LB  RB  N     Pcnt1
0   1   3  2  0.500000
1   3   5  1  1.000000
2   5   7  0       NaN
3   7   9  3  0.666667
4   9  11  1  1.000000
```

(This uses the RB-exclusive convention.)

---

Here all the hard work is done by `pd.cut`, which returns a Series of category dtype:

```
>>> bins
0     [1, 3)
1     [1, 3)
2     [3, 5)
3     [7, 9)
4     [7, 9)
5     [7, 9)
6    [9, 11)
Name: x, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [[1, 3) < [3, 5) < [5, 7) < [7, 9) < [9, 11)]
```

Since we want to align on the bounds, I dropped down to the underlying bin indices:

```
>>> bins.values.codes
array([0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4], dtype=int8)
```

Note that if we have an element which doesn't fit in a bin, say 100, then the categorical will give NaN and the code -1, and so it'll (correctly) be skipped when we insert into `df_new`.